# JMeter: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

Tags: parameters, jmeter, response

I am trying to hit 1k users with synchronization timer, and can see below response:

java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

I have added following:

1. http.connection.stalecheck$Boolean=true in hc.parameter file
2. httpclient4.retrycount=1

   hc.parameter.file=hc.parameter

Is there anything that I am missing to add on?

Comment: What is the connection timeout set in the server?

Comment: 300 Secs is timeout set

Comment: it's possible that your test is exhausting available ports, causing client to wait for port, and sometimes timing out. You can confirm that by running 150+150 clients from 2 JMeter hosts. If that works, it's even more likely. If you are on windows, start from doing registry changes this article suggests (esp. related to TIME_WAIT): msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560610(v=bts.20).aspx (it's about biztalk, but really it applies to any other port exhaustion). On Linux similar process is described here: lognormal.com/blog/2012/09/27/linux-tcpip-tuning